# How to remove a specific document from sanity desk structure?

Tags: javascript, sanity

I added the media library plugin to my sanity structure builder but want to remove the 'media tag' document that gets created by the plugin

> However, you can override this behaviour by defining your own custom desk with Sanity's structure builder and simply omit the media.tag document type in your definition

I am unclear on how to do this with my current structure

```
  plugins: [
    deskTool({
      structure: pageStructure([home, settings]),

      defaultDocumentNode: previewDocumentNode({ apiVersion, previewSecretId }),
    }),

    singletonPlugin([home.name, settings.name]),

    productionUrl({
      apiVersion,
      previewSecretId,
      types: PREVIEWABLE_DOCUMENT_TYPES,
    }),
    media(),
    vercelDeployTool(),
    visionTool({ defaultApiVersion: apiVersion }),
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I hid the Media Tag document type from the desk:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    deskTool({
      structure: (S) =>
        S.list()
          .title('Content')
          .items([...S.documentTypeListItems().filter((item) => item.getId() !== 'media.tag')]),
    }),
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The project is setup in `JSON`.
The functions you call are probably also returning `JSON`. So there should be an easy workaround for this.

One of the functions adds a property `media.tag` with their value. (I don't know which function exactly but you can find out easily by printing each object in your `plugins` array).

Once you found this out, you can make use of the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator in JavaScript.

Here is a simple example which you can derive pretty easy:

```js
const plugins = {
    // other properties here
    media: {
        tag: "plugin-tag",
        // other properties here
    },
}

delete plugins.media.tag // returns true if property deleted.

/*
Plugins object after deletion of `media.tag`:

const plugins = {
    // other properties here
    media: {
        // other properties here
    },
}
*/
```

**⚠️ Note:** I treated `tag` as if it is a property on the `media` object, if `media.tag` is the name of a single property, use the bracket notation (`["media.tag"]`) instead.

Once you have done this, you have "omitted the media.tag document type in your definition" and you should be good to go.